# How to display my search to my table in VueJs?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I just want to ask, I want to display the searched value in my table?
Below code displays Memb_ID in *div*.

```
div>
    <div class="search-wrapper">
      <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search title..">
      <label>Search title:</label>
    </div>

 <div v-for="cust in filteredList" :key="cust.id">{{ cust.Memb_ID }}</div>

<div class="myTable table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th>Member ID</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Middle Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <!-- <th>URL</th> -->
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="result in results" :key="result.id">
          <td>{{result.Memb_ID}}</td>
          <th>{{result.First_Name}}</th>
          <th>{{result.Middle_Name}}</th>
          <th>{{result.Last_Name}}</th>
          <th>{{result.Address}}</th>
          <!-- <th>{{user.url}}</th> -->
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

This is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59Cgg.jpg) of my code. 
I want something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvFk0.jpg)

I got the code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52959195/bootstrap-vue-b-table-with-filter-in-header) but couldn't implement on my own. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

So I thought I solved my problem by looping in the table body.
There's a bug in here. Every time I reload the page it doesn't load the vue file lol. I thought it was okay after refreshing the page it didn't display the table.

I don't know the bug

```
<div>
    <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search title..">
  </div>
  <div class="myTable table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th>Member ID</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Middle Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="result in filteredList" :key="result.id">
          <td>{{result.Memb_ID}}</td>
          <th>{{result.First_Name}}</th>
          <th>{{result.Middle_Name}}</th>
          <th>{{result.Last_Name}}</th>
          <th>{{result.Address}}</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

and in script

```
computed: {
filteredList() {
  return this.results.filter(customer => {
    customer.Memb_ID.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
  });
}
```

},